# ¿Por qué MySQL no valida la contraseña si está en mayúscula o minúscula?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me deja ingresar así ponga la contraseña en minúscula o mayúscula, qué puedo hacer para no tener que comparar texto con JavaScript o no sé.

```php
<?php
$login = mysqli_query($base, "SELECT *FROM $tabla WHERE user = '$user' AND password = '$password'");

if (count(mysqli_fetch_array($login)) > 0) {
  echo '<h1 class="text">Hola</h1>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Prueba con `SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE user = '$user' AND password = binary '$password'`

Comment: Esto tiene que ver con lo que se conoce como [`COLLATION` en MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/). Son reglas para comparar los valores de las columnas. Si ejecutas un `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;` verás que la columna que refieres tiene una `COLLATION` que termina en `_ci`, lo cual significa *case insensitive* o lo que es lo mismo: insensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas para fines de comparación. De todos modos, para contraseñas se recomienda guardar un hash y comparar ese hash con password_verify.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola, saludos!, para empezar sugiero revises un poco la sintaxis, PHP puede ser algo especial si no se "respeta" la escritura del código, aunque realmente puede funcionar como quiere, sugiero revises tu conexión a la BD y que la consulta te esté devolviendo lo que esperas, ya que puede a veces no funcionar como lo esperamos a su vez que los campos que consultas sean del tipo que consultas, es decir varchar con 'texto'.

```
<?php
    $login = mysqli_query($base, "SELECT * FROM ".$tabla." WHERE user='".$user."' AND password='".$password."'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_fetch_array($login)) == 1) {
        echo "<h1 class='text'>¡Hola usuario!</h1>";
    }
?>
```

De igual forma podrías probar usando mysqli_num_rows, funciona exponiendo el número de registros que te ha devuelto la consulta, que para como la intentas hacer, será o deberá ser, 1.

¡Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Esta afectando directamente a la base de datos.
Configura en

- lower_case_table_names

A mi me funciono.

Saludos